# How to configure GeoServer WMS with no internet connectivity?

Tags: geoserver, wms, offline, standalone

I am trying to configure GeoServer so that it works with no internet connectivity. When I try to access the GetSchemaExtension, by default, it goes out to the internet for this url:
http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd

Is there a configuration out there that allows this file (among many other files) to be configured so that they are accessed internally? I can download the necessary files and upload them onto the server.

Comment: can you include the GeoServer version?

Comment: have you tried http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/app-schema-resolution.html